# Search shows results for /Pages/foldername AND /Pages/foldername/default.aspx

Tags: search, search-results, crawl-rules

I'm finding that my SharePoint 2010 search results are showing results for both a folder and that folders default.aspx page. For example, my results can look like this:

```
products
<description taken from default.aspx page>
http://myserver/Pages/foldername

Product One - Information
<description taken from default.aspx page>
http://myserver/Pages/foldername/default.aspx
```

Ideally I want to remove/exclude the results for the folders, leaving just the default.aspx pages in the results.

Can anyone help me out with a crawl rule to produce the desired results? Either a 'standard' `*://*...` style rule or a regular expression?

Comment: Have you tried to reindex the crawl database?

Comment: Yes. Can you expand on why this might help? I mean, as folder not meant to show in results, or is there some other reason I might not be aware of?

Comment: Kevin, can you tell me exactly where you put that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the search returns with the query you use, and not have to change the crawl rule.

For example, If you are searching for "Product", you can enter the following into the search query box:

Product IsDocument:1

and you should only get documents and not folders.

You can configure the query web part to automatically append IsDocument:1 to all searches, so users don't need to enter it on all searches.

**Update:**

You enter the extra query terms in the Search Box Web Part. See screenshot.
[image: Search Box Extra Query Terms]

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a publishing site, used by customers and prospective customers. We can't expect them to know to use IsDocument:1

So, back to excluding them by default - crawl rules being the best way. Any ideas?

Comment: you can automatically and silently append (behind the scenes) extra query terms without users knowing about them. You could add IsDocument:1  and there is probably a flag to say "is not a folder" too.

Comment: Sorry, I just spotted that you essentially said that in your original answer (I should have my first cup of Tea BEFORE replying to posts <g>). My search results page is a copy of 'osssearchresults.aspx', so I assume the web configurations would be done on `<SearchWC:CoreResultsWebPart runat="server" ShowActionLinks=false ChromeType="None"/>`? I'll check around to see what I can find, unless you happen to know what I need to add and where?

Comment: I found it :) I updated my ASPX webpart element to be: `<SearchWC:CoreResultsWebPart runat="server" ShowActionLinks=false  ChromeType="None" AppendedQuery="IsDocument:1"/>` and now I get documents only. Plus I found the MS page that lists all the properties, so I have so fun times ahead trying them out :) Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, with screenshot. I'm sure that will help others. In my case I was working with an custom application page in the /_layouts/ folder (a copy of osssearchresults.aspx), so could only edit the .aspx page directly. However, my comment above achieved the same goal as your UI based update.